# Forcing Common Lisp not to evaluate symbol to variable

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm currently working on a macro/function which I will use as an alternative method to declare lists, namely to use [ and ] instead of the usual '(a b c) way to do it.

Though I'm having some problems, namely that I always have to write quotes before the symbols (as they aren't bound to variables I get an error msg), how would I go about to remove the need for these quotes?

Also, the main reason that I want to introduce this alternative way to declare lists in Common Lisp is because it sometimes tends to be cluttered with parenthesis's and if I actually want to call my function/macro I'll need to enclose it with parens, how would I go about to remove the needs for those?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code? You might want to look at reader macros for your actual task of using `[]` instead of `()`. Take a look here, which has that exact example: http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter03-12.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with reader macros.  (Reader macros are something completely different from "ordinary" macros, by the way.)

However, before you muck around in the readtable, I would strongly recommend that you learn Lisp.  Do not fight the parentheses!  They are the only syntax you have, so use them!

For learning, I recommend Peter Seibel's ["Practical Common Lisp"](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Comment: Yep, a reader macro is definitely the way to go. Would probably require a call to READ-DELIMITED-LIST and a few calls to SET-SYNTAX-FROM-CHAR. Probably a decent-difficulty "first faffing about with readtables" project, but I agree taht getting to grips with CL is something that should come first.

Comment: Johan, If you plan on using @Svante's code for more than a throwaway, I recommend you check out this library: https://common-lisp.net/project/named-readtables/. It lets you package up reader macros in named tables, providing the kind of organization defpackage provides for symbols.

I wrote some code here (https://bitbucket.org/blevyq/short-lambda) that defines reader macros for #\\[ and #\\] using named readtables. It may give you a good starting point for your macros.